# How do I set rest pose to editor pose?

Tags: rigging, bones

My rest pose is wrong and I want the locations from edit mode. I accidentally changed the rest position so when I clear transforms it goes to wrong position, and I obviously can't work with it. I also have other changes done so I can't just take the backup. How can I fix this?

Here you can see the pose mode and edit mode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you applied pose as rest pose, I mean, to obtain the situation you are in ?

Comment: Accidentally. I can't revert it because I have made other changes. I really don't want to recreate the bones.

Comment: To me, the initial positions of the bones are lost... but maybe someone will have a solution...

Comment: Have a look at the auto backup files (.blend1, ...)

Comment: @ArturTerho, please edit your question so that it does not get closed (or can be reopened) It needs to include these new details from the comments, as well as a more thorough description of what you're trying to accomplish. Screenshots might be appropriate.

Comment: @ArturTerho It's helpful to remember that this is not a forum. So it works a little differently from what you might expect.

Comment: If I understand well your edit, you did not applied the pose as rest pose ? Am I wrong ? If I am not, simply select all the bones in pose mode and go to the "pose/clear transform/all" menu.

Comment: @lemon The first picture is result of doing that. Why would I show a picture of irrelevant pose?

Comment: You will need to do everything over. That's the general learning process with Blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Blender normaly the "Edit Pose" is automatically the "Rest Pose", so as long as you did not some weird stuff, this should also be the the case in your project.

For me your screenshot of the pose mode looks like you have a problem in your IK constraint. To check this, you have to disable the ik constraint of your lower leg bone (or what ever it is). if your bone snaps back to its original position, the ik constrain is the problem.